# Does $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by f(x) = $x^2$ have any identity function?

Tags: functions

I'm confused as to when functions can have an identity function or not. I remember seeing that functions don't need to be invertible to have an identity function. Can someone explain, maybe with some type of restriction, how $f(x) = x^2$ can have an identity function?

I'm still trying to have this whole inverse topic click for me.

Edit: By '$f$ has an identity function', I mean does there exist a $g$ such that $g(f(x)) = id$?

Comment: What does ”f has an identity function” mean?

Comment: Like, maybe in some cases, f(g(b)) = b for all b but g(f(a)) doesnt equal a for all a. By 'f has an identity function' I mean can someone give me an example where the input is mapped to itself?

Comment: I can only guess, but could it be that you mean the existence of a function $g$ such that $f\circ g={\rm id}$, or also $g\circ f={\rm id}$? Then one function has to injective, the other surjective - see for duplicates on this site. Is $x\mapsto x^2$ injective on $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes, I'm sorry if I phrased it horrendously

Comment: @DietrichBurde thats great thanks